# Elmah 1.2.1 ASP.NET MVC3 admin/elmah.axd working but detail pages, RSS etc. not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

I've ELMAH 1.2.1 is working in my ASP.NET MVC 3 site. I'm using an admin/elmah.axd URL approach. But when I try to drill down into detail pages, or the RSS feeds, etc., I get 404 errors.

Why would admin/elmah.axd be working for me, but not detail pages such as /admin/elmah.axd/detail/?id=F983FCAD-98C3-4665-B8E3-A9C00E30B510, or the RSS feed or downloadable logs?

Here is a Glimpse screenshot of my route configurations:
[image]

Here are how I define my routes, which are all initialized on application startup:

```
    RouteCollection routes = RouteTable.Routes;
    routes.Clear();
    routes.IgnoreRoute("cms/");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.htm");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.png");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.gif");

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

I also tried the wildcard mapping issue at http://groups.google.com/group/elmah/browse_thread/thread/c22b85ace3812da1, although that seems to be a pretty old thread and perhaps an issue with just that version on ASP.NET.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the `{*pathInfo}` part on your ignoreRoute call?

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

**EDIT**
Let's see if glimpse can help us solve this.

1. Intall the [glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) mvc nugget package:   "Glimpse.Mvc3" version="0.86"
2. Visit /glimpse.axd and turn glimpse on.
3. Now visit the details page and lets see what glimpse reports.

Now you should see the route debugging info.
[image]
Hopefully that gives enough info to figure out what the problem is. I am very curious as to what the problem is.

**EDIT 2**
Try adding this to your http handler section in web.config

```
<add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd/rss" type="Elmah.ErrorRssHandler, Elmah" />
```

Check if the rss feed works now.
There seems to be an [issue with wildcard mapping](http://groups.google.com/group/elmah/browse_thread/thread/c22b85ace3812da1) which might be to blame here.

Comment: Thanks...I have tried these variations without success, and a couple of others. Realistically the first one, which is what you've suggested, should catch it: routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");             routes.IgnoreRoute("admin/elmah.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: Try the basic setup first. Can you test if it works using the standard /elmah.axd path? (leave out the admin path for now)

Comment: Tried just now, same result...I reconfigured httpHandlers under system.webServer (IIS 7.x) and I'm able to access http://localhost:12000/elmah.axd. But as soon as I try to access any ELMAH sub-pages such as http://localhost:12000/elmah.axd/rss/, I get the same HTTP 404.

Comment: @ShanPlourde I can reproduce the problem by using routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/") -> leaving out the *pathInfo part. How are you defining your route?

Comment: Hi Santiago, thanks for your continued help. Glimpse is a neat little diagnostic tool, but it reveals that my IgnoreRoutes are configured properly (I edited my question to include a screenshot of Glimpse running locally). I am always able to view my root Elmah.axd, but as soon as I try to drill down into pages such as elmah.axd/rss/ I get 404's. It might be something else in my processing pipeline perhaps, just not sure what.

Comment: @ShanPlourde some hope. Check Edit 2 above.

Comment: Tried that too SantiagoIT. Thanks...I think I'm about ready to toss ELMAH down the drain. For some reason I'm just not lucky with it